# Will the string obtained from http request be saved in the constant pool?

Tags: java, string, permgen

I understand that String declared as the following will be saved in the constant pool:

eg.

```
String a = "test';
```

then test will be saved in the pool

I wonder if the String acquired from a method, eg.from a request parameter posted from a web form, or read from a file.
Eg.

```
String name = request.getRequestParameter("name");
```

Will the value in name be saved in constant pool? I assume it's not? because otherwise you would soon have out of memory perm gen error?

Can anyone please enlighten me ?

Thanks

Comment: Only the string literals are in the constant pool. Anything else would need an explicit invocation of `intern` to get there.

Comment: So the value in "name" will not be saved in constant pool and soon will be garbage collected? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. When and how strings are `intern`ed is described in the [`String#intern` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) and the JLS [Section 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5). Basically, literals and (other) string constants are auto-interned, but nothing else is likely to be unless you do it explicitly.

As a side point, you seem to be assuming that interned strings are never garbage-collected. I don't see anything in the Java documentation actually *saying* that, and [at least one person](http://blog.kdgregory.com/2009/09/intern-isnt-forever-and-maybe-never-was.html) claims that his tests show that they are, in fact, GC'd, suggesting that the intern pool uses some form of weak reference.

Comment: Perhaps start with a line that says "No". That after all is the basic answer.

Comment: Thanks，Yes I assumed interned strings are never garbage collected, but I did some test myself, it turns out it didn't give me the permgen out of memory error.

Comment: +1 I tested the code from that blog and can confirm the finding.

Comment: Thanks TJ, so that means we  never need to worry about memory issues for String, for example, if someone posts a huge string from a webform and application handles it in local method, then it will get garbage collected eventually.

Comment: @grumpynerd: Yeah. I mean, there's always the question of GC "pauses," but HotSpot's GC is very mature and multi-tiered (as you seem to know), and there are plenty of high-performance servers that have to be doing lots of string ops (Netty, Jetty, Tomcat is pretty high-performance these days), so...